# Time complexity of the recursive function which finds the pair in the array with given sum

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time, time-complexity, analysis

```
private static void findTheSumUsingRecursion(int[] array, int sum, int first_index, int second_index) {

    //End of recursion condition: the first element to check is the last element in the array.
    // This also works with input arrays with fewer than two elements.
    if (first_index >= array.length - 1) {
        System.out.println("Total number of pair is: "+ counter);
        return;
    }

    // The sub-array has been depleted. Move ahead that the very first element to the next index and relate it to the remaining array elements.
    if (second_index >= array.length) {
        findTheSumUsingRecursion(array, sum, first_index + 1, first_index + 2);
        return;
    }
    // If the sum of the first and second element of the array is equals to sum, increment the counter.
    if (array[first_index] + array[second_index] == sum) {
       counter++;
    }

    //Compare the first array element to the next array element.
    findTheSumUsingRecursion(array, sum, first_index, second_index + 1);
}
```

I tried to calculate this function's time complexity by using a recurrence relationship but I can not handle the situation.
This is how I think:

[image]

How can I calculate the time complexity of this method?

Comment: Master Theorem does not apply here. This algorithm does not subdivide and recombine.

Comment: Count the number of array element comparisons. You don't need recursion to calculate this